# Prevent drop-down menu to close

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a big problem. I want to prevent an opened drop-down menu to close when hovering another menu item. How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Regards
Marius

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the event that's called when you are hovering another item, probably `LostFocus`or `LostMouseCapture`, look at the function called aith this event (`OnLostFocus` or `OnLostMouseCapture`) and override this method like this :

```
public override void OnLostFocus()
{
    base.OnLostFocus();
    Popup popup = Template.FindName("PART_Popup", this) as Popup;
    popup.IsOpen = true;
}
```

This way, the event won't close the drop down menu. (The example above is for a combobox)

I'm not sure about the right event to override. It depends on your problem. You can find the list of event [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox_events%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if these are not the right ones. But I think that's the way you should do it.